# iPhone developer simulator can't create sandbox Game Center account

Tags: networking, iphone, ios, emulator, development

I am developing an iPhone game and I'm trying to create a Game Center account on the iPhone simulator. However, I get a message "game center account services are currently unavailable.  Please try again later."

Furthermore, I have never been able to sign in to the game center app on the simulator.

I get the same errors on an actual iPhone as well, but I recognize this part is off topic on this site. I include the information just so you have all the information.

Interestingly, if I reset my device with iTunes, I *can* then log in to the Game Center app with my regular apple id.  But whenever if I log out, then try to create a sandbox account for an app I am developing, it always fails as described above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I see some people are voting to close this.  I will say that it sure as hell leaves me stuck in my attempt to create my game center iOS app.  I imagine other programmers have encountered the same problem.  Additionally, per the [faq], questions about software tools commonly used by developers are relevant, and the sandbox is such a tool.

Comment: Did the two migrate voters even bother to read the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by my router.  If I turned off my firewall, everything worked.  Hardly a viable long-term solution.  Apple has [instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4307) for fixing this with port forwarding.  It turned out my router was too old to get those to work -- so I had to buy a newer router, then implement the port forwarding.  That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this problem when the date on my iPhone 3GS is incorrect.  The date seems to revert to January 1st, 1970 if I let the power drain completely.  I can't connect to Game Center when the date is too far in the past.

The problem is, I always forget about this clock change problem (which also affects facebook login), and spend a while searching the Internet for answers before I remember the clock bug!